# String in array into another array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to set an array to a string from another array. This is in C programming.

```
gates[gatenum]=&seperation[a+1];
```

where both `a` and `gatenum` are both ints. And both arrays are declared as:

```
char seperation[3000][100];
char *gates[100][10];
```

So basically what I'm asking is how can I set `gates[gatenum]` to the string that is in `seperation[a+1]`

Thank you in advance

Comment: I still get the same compiling error when I get rid of the `&`. Yeah I just want to copy the string from seperation to gates.

Comment: Are the arrays really declared like that? One is char * and the other is just char?

Comment: gates is still char * and the other is just char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the second dimension of gates.

char *gates[100];

Then you can assign gates[gatenum] = seperation[a+1];

Comment: That worked thank you. I'd up vote you but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy(gates,seperation,sizeof(gates));`